# Facing issue while exporting at 1920x1080p in principle for mac

Tags: macos, animation, prototyping

Am using **Principle for Mac** prototyping application, I have tried to export the sample video in the size of 1920x1080p. After exporting the video is not rendered properly, it stays in the first frame. Could you please help me about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this, Principle application could not able to construct the interaction for the heavy file (i.e, my file has more than 50 slides) this is the major for the issue.

Thank you:)